# Separate numbers from letters in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

In many documents that I'm indexing with Lucene, people accidentally concatenate words with numbers. For instance, one could say: "I was born in2000", instead of "I was born in 2000".

Is there any Lucene tokenizer that can separate words with numbers (e.g. in2000and) into several words (e.g. in 2000 and)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory) and add splitOnNumerics=1 param to your schema.

Comment: I'm not using Solr. So I downloaded WordDelimiterFilter and WordDelimiterIterator from Solr.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using Solr. So I downloaded WordDelimiterFilter and WordDelimiterIterator from Solr., and added this code to my custom analyzer:

```
    final Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer(matchVersion, reader);
    TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(matchVersion, source);
    int flags = WordDelimiterFilter.SPLIT_ON_NUMERICS
                | WordDelimiterFilter.GENERATE_NUMBER_PARTS
                | WordDelimiterFilter.GENERATE_WORD_PARTS;
    result = new WordDelimiterFilter(result, flags, null);
```